# How to build only the selected class library project in Visual Studio, not any dependencies

Tags: c#

We have a *very* large solution.  I'd like to find a way to select a C# class library project in Visual Studio and build only that project.

The solution is composed of non-managed C++, managed C++, and C# projects.

Turning on "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" results in very good performance with executables, it only compiles the executable assembly.

But selecting a C# class library project and selecting Build Project still goes off and builds all these C++ projects.

Comment: You could always create a smaller solution that has only what you need in it.

Comment: Whenever possible I have done that to improve productivity, but before checking in I need to make sure everything is working in the large solution shared by the team.

Comment: If a library which is a dependency needs to be compiled then Visual Studio will compile it.  The solution is to make sure thats not required.  Sounds like your linking Solution A to the output of Solution B.  You can solve this by putting all solution outputs should be in the same directory.  This means if the dependency already exists it won't be compiled.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do that. If project A references project B, then the compiler has to compile both projects in order to compile A. One way out of this would be to include the reference to project B as an assembly, not a project reference. That way, project A depends on the compiled result of project B and the compiler does not need to build it every time. Having an assembly reference though is something I dislike because you have to manage assembly versions and probably check-in binaries into your source control which I dislike as well.

Having said all of this, your build should be incremental. If nothing has changed in the projects from last build, they should be very quick. Perhaps something in your build setup is introducing a defect in such a way that your build is no longer incremental. If you have custom pre/post build steps, examine those to make sure nothing of this sort is happening.

Comment: Unfortunately assembly references are not an option here, only project references.  I think the custom pre/post build steps are the issue (signing, etc), but again changing them is not an option.

Comment: If your pre/post build steps are doing unnecessary work, you should be able to change them so that they don't; that wouldn't change their semantics or results. If something is preventing your build from being incremental, it's a defect.